# c# not accessing reader sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

so i have this class that has c# functions to work with reserving and freeing seats. Anyway, In debug mode, the while is checked then suddenly its content is skipped. I assume that there is no resultset returned for read to actually access? but what could I do? because this code was working and suddenly it stopped...

```
 string queryRangeForCheck = "select * from DateTest WHERE datefill between @startdate AND @enddate";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("....");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryRangeForCheck, conn);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", startDate);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", endDate);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        int bookingStatus = 2;
        //for the range found do:
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            //establish the number of seats available for this date
            int currentRow = Convert.ToInt32(reader["seats"]); 
            //if the number is > 0 i.e. if not fully booked

            if (currentRow != 0)
            {
                //if the number of seats can accomodate the number required
                if (currentRow >= requiredSeats)
                {
                  ....
```

Please advice
Thanks

Comment: The only thing strange/bad with your code is that you don't enclose your db connection in an `using` statement and it's not clear whether you dispose it or not later on.

Comment: if it skipped then there is no data matching the conditions in the DB... so you either check the data in the DB or handle this situation in code...

Comment: I do dispose it but I don't know about the using thing...because am quite new in C# (like a month new). Will make sure I add it. because the dates are sent as function parameters, I discovered that their format is other than the expected, hence the fault. Still working on it.

Comment: yes @Yahia this is true...am working on confirming it

Comment: uhmmm i think not all of the possible routes of the while loop closes the data reader before it proceeds to the next route

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if the reader has rows using the HasRows property.

Moreover, create a new table and load the table with the reader. This will close the reader, but you will be able to use the data-set debug visualizer to inspect the results. Then just execute the command again. In the following code snippet, the command returns multiple result sets. Therefore, I keep loading tables until the reader is closed during a call to the Load method.

```
            oReader = Me.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection Or CommandBehavior.KeyInfo)

#If DbDebug Then

        'load method internally advances to the next result set
        'therefore, must check to see if reader is closed instead of calling next result

        Do
            Dim oTable As New DataTable("Table")
            oTable.Load(oReader)
            'Inspect oTable here as needed.
            oTable.WriteXml("C:\" + Environment.TickCount.ToString + ".xml")
            oTable.Dispose()
        Loop While oReader.IsClosed = False

        'must re-open the connection
        Me.SelectCommand.Connection.Open()

        'reload data reader
        oReader = Me.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection Or CommandBehavior.KeyInfo)

#End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue was confirmed to be that the reader returned nothing. This is due to the type and format of the date parameters passed and expected. Hence it didn't match, and failed to return any results. When the date was re-formatted in mm/dd/yyyy it actually all worked. Thanks to everyone for their great input :)

Comment: IF you pass in Date Objects instead of date strings should not cause formatting issues.